# Case sensitive string replacement Objective C

Tags: objective-c, replace, nsstring

I need to replace a substring from a string that is case sensitive. For example in the following string:

```
replace the String with a string
```

I need to replace the word `String` with capital `S` with `sentence` but the other `string` has to be un affected. What can I do to achieve this? I have tried with `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` but it is case insensitive.

Comment: Sigh!  Please read the spec for NSString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:
```

and don't use `NSCaseInsensitiveSearch` option.

Comment: He already knows that, since that's obviously the option he's using.

Comment: Instead of `NSCaseInsensitiveSearch` what option should be used?

Comment: @HarikrishnanT Pass in `0` for no options.

Comment: Great flow of conversation. :-)